# How can you execute a method from a sub class of a super class, when you are calling it from a sub class from another sup class?

Tags: c#, superclass

I currently am building a rest API with asp net core. I was following this tutorial from Medium, which is a tutorial about Repository pattern implementations. Here is the [Link](https://medium.com/net-core/repository-pattern-implementation-in-asp-net-core-21e01c6664d7).

I have 2 superclasses, each one has a subclass. I have Superclass TController and TService and the subclasses UserController and UserService. I want to call from UserController a method of UserService. The method is defined in UserService but not in the superclass of TService.

So my question is: **How can you execute a method set in UserController, when you are calling it from UserController?**

Here is the controller:

```
public abstract class TController<TEntity, TService> : ControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TService : IService<TEntity>
{

    private TService service;

    public TController(TService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntity>>> Get()
    {
        return await this.service.GetAll();
    }

    [Methods GetId, Add, Update, Delete, but cut out to keep the code short]

}

public class UserController : TController<UserModel, UserService>
{
    public UserController(UserService service): base(service)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("/check")]
    public bool Check()
    {


        return base.CheckPassword("Bollox")
    }

}
```

And here is the service:

```
 public interface IService<T> where T: class, IEntity
{
    Task<List<T>> GetAll();
    [Methods GetId, Add, Update, Delete, but cut out to keep the code short]
}

public abstract class TService<TEntity, TRepository>: IService<TEntity>
    where TEntity: class, IEntity
    where TRepository: IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private TRepository repository;

    public TService(TRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll()
    {
        return await this.repository.GetAll();
    }


}

public class UserService : TService<UserModel, UserRepository>
{
    public UserService(UserRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {

    }

    public bool CheckPassword(String password)
    {

        return true;

    }

}
```

I have tried to define UserService twice, which works, but is there any better way?

```
 public class UserController : TController<UserModel, UserService>
{
    private readonly UserService svc;

    public UserController(UserService service): base(service)
    {
        this.svc = service;
    }

    [HttpGet("/check")]
    public bool Check()
    {


        return svc.CheckPassword(new UserModel
        {
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: None of the classes in the code are called `A`, `B`, `a` or `b`. Can you provide some code that is more relevant to the question you've asked?

Comment: You should just refer to the classes in your code, there's no reason to speak in analogies

Comment: Too much code for what you described

Comment: You might try creating a common class, or helper class. It can get a little tricky keeping things generic, you'll have to be careful not to put too much into the common class and abuse it...

Comment: You want to call `UserService.CheckPasswaord` from `UserController`..... isn't that exactly what you've done? I also dont get "I have tried to define UserService twice, which works, but is there any better way?" - where is it ddefined twice? why?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, but UserService will be initialized in two places

Comment: @MichaelZiegler Are you talking about using injection?  Your post talks about inheritance, if you want to reuse a single service class, register it in your startup configuration as a singleton

Comment: oooh just make it `protected` in the base class. itll still work because its generic. I'll write you an answer.

Comment: No, only one instance is present. `UserController` will effectively contain two fields with the "same" instance, but that's an implementation detail. You can choose to expose the field on the base as `protected` (although a property would be more appropriate), but "redeclaring" it in the derived class is certainly not wrong either (it avoids assumptions about what the base is doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option of just making `service` protected in the base class - as you're using generic you still have access to all of `UserService`

```
public abstract class TController<TEntity, TService> : ControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TService : IService<TEntity>
{

    protected readonly TService service;

    public TController(TService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TEntity>>> Get()
    {
        return await this.service.GetAll();
    }

    [Methods GetId, Add, Update, Delete, but cut out to keep the code short]

}
```

You can then use it directly in the derived class:

```
public class UserController : TController<UserModel, UserService>
{
    public UserController(UserService service): base(service)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet("/check")]
    public bool Check()
    {


        return service.CheckPassword(new UserModel
        {
        });
    }

}
```